# How to update a dictionary in multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am trying to update a dictionary in a python code which is paralleled with multiprocessing. Unfortunately, I cannot share my code, because it is quite complicated but I will try to explain my problem.

First of all, I don't have a shared dictionary and for some reason, the dictionary should be created in every process separately. The problem will arise when I add an element to this dictionary.
every time that I add a new key: value to the dictionary, all values of the previous keys become equal to the new value. Something like this...

```
def func():
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['first'] = 1
    my_dict['second'] = 2
    print(my_dict) 

import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(2)
pool.map(func)
```

The results will be something like this

```
my_dict = {'first':2, 'second':2}
```

I also used Manager().dict() but I encounter several problems so I decided to ask first.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to solve the problem.  func is trivial and works as expected.  It would not be impacted by pool.map as written.

Comment: First of all, your posted code cannot run since your call to `pool.map(func)` needs to be passed an *iterable* as the second argument, which is clearly missing. Second, I am highly skeptical that both keys in the dictionary end up having the same value. You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this and what you posted is not it.

Answer (score 0):

`my_dict` is not shared or sync between processes in your example, I think it should be okay.
I run

```
def func(_):
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['first'] = 1
    my_dict['second'] = 2
    print(my_dict)

import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(2)
pool.map(func, range(2))
```

For python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 18.04.5, it outputs

```
{'first': 1, 'second': 2}
{'first': 1, 'second': 2}
```

Comment: That is exactly my problem. It should work, but it doesn't. In my code I use this to run everything parallel
```
    with mp.Pool((nproc)) as p:
        with tqdm(total=ctrl.max_points) as pbar:
            for _ in p.imap_unordered(partial(main_func, params=params), iter(f)):
                pbar.update()
```

Comment: I suggest you provide information about your python and platform, it might be a bug of the python build you use. And you can install another python version.